# Constructing the matrix of the differentiation linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

For every integer $n > 1$ choose a basis in the space $P_n(F)$ of polynomials of
degree not bigger than $n$, and construct the matrix of the differentiation linear operator
$P_n(F)\longrightarrow P_{n−1}(F): p \mapsto p'$.

I don't know how to start so hints would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, *take* a basis. For example:
$$\lbrace1,x,x^2,\cdots,x^n\rbrace$$
On the elements of this basis, your operator is:
$$Dx^k=k x^{k-1}.$$
Can you countinue?

Answer (score 0):

Like in the previous answer, take that basis and recall that the columns of the matrix of the operator are the coefficients of the images of these basis elements by this operator.